# Unity - Help needed with spherical gravity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game which has strong base on spherical gravity. But somehow my code is not working as expected. So please have a look at my code and tell me how can I make my spherical gravity work.

```
public class CircularGravity : MonoBehaviour {
    private Rigidbody2D rigid;
    [SerializeField]
    Transform planet;

    [SerializeField]
    float acceleration = 0.81f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        rigid.AddForce((planet.position - transform.position).normalized * acceleration);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(planet.position - transform.position, transform.up);
    }
}
```

[image]
Problem elaboration. Project is 2d. it contains a circle sprite as a planet with a collider and hexagon has a player(just a prototype) with collider and rigidbody. This script is attached to the player(hexagon). According to my logic rigidbody should apply a force to the player and push it towards the planet and it should face the planet. So even if the player is on the downward side of circle it shouldnot fall instead it shall be pushed toward the planet. But all the colliders are being neglected and player is just going to strange position

Comment: Thanks for adding code to your question but what's not working? What is spherical gravity?

Comment: @Programmer well that is also called faux gravity like in the game super mario galaxy. Once google that

Comment: @programmer my player was supposed to stick around the planet but it is going towards the centre of planet

Comment: @SamratLuitel Well that's the point of gravity, to pull you to the center of the planet. There's probably a problem with your colliders.

Comment: @Cnuts Ok you are not getting. Create a 2d project. use a circle as a planet and apply a collider to it. And then create a hexagon with collider and a rigidbody and use my script. You will understand what is actually happening

Comment: @SamratLuitel Perhaps you could include an annotated screenshot or a GIF to indicate the problem behaviour? Generally questions should be self-contained (ie. Shouldn't require external resources or recreating the project to understand them.)

Comment: @Serlite I do understand but that can be done in couple of minutes I guess. And most of them are not familiar with spherical gravity So I dont think screenshot is gonna help

Comment: @Programmer question makes any sense now

Comment: @SamratLuitel Are you sure that they are on the same axis and that they are actually colliding?

Comment: Are you saying the player is going through the planet rather than staying on the surface?

Comment: @Matt L exactly

Comment: @Programmer it is circle2d on planet and polygon on player

Answer (score 2):

First things I would check...

- Make sure the origin of your sprite is actually in the center of the image.  If it's in the corner the player will be pulled toward the corner.
- Make sure both the planet and player have rigid bodies and colliders. Click on the collider and make sure the edge lines up with you shapes.
- Make sure both the planet and the player have their z set to zero.  Lock z in both rigidbodies.

Comment: Also make sure that gravity is turned off on the rigidbodies (not sure if this is relevant for 2D).

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the Rigidbody settings are as shown below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezuit.png)

since we are in a 2D environment, We must have movement in the two-dimensional axis.
This is your modified Script:

```
  private Rigidbody2D rigid;
    [SerializeField]
    Transform planet;

    [SerializeField]
    float acceleration = 0.81f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rigid.AddForce((planet.position - transform.position).normalized * 
         acceleration);
        Quaternion temp = Quaternion.LookRotation(planet.position - 
        transform.position, transform.up);
        temp.x = 0;
        temp.y = 0;
        transform.rotation = temp;
    }
```